# Issues reaching docker containers on Linux server running Photon OS 4.0

Tags: docker, photon-os

We have a Linux server which runs Photon OS 4.0. We use this server to run docker containers. Prior to updating to Photon OS 4.0, the server was running Photon OS 3.0. All the containers in this server was running as expected with no issues. However after updating the server to Photon 4.0, we cant reach any of the docker containers via internet. I verified the Iptables with a server running Photon OS 3.0 and nothing stands out as different. The containers are running in the server and there are no errors, but we cant reach it via internet.

this is a snippet of the Docker file i am using for one of the containers.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
ENV TZ=Canada/Mountain
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY publish/ .
COPY Certificates/ .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MaximoHomePage.dll"]
```

and this is the docker-compose I'm using

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  maximohomepage.test:
    image: maximohomepage:test
    container_name: maximohomepage-test
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=ExAXBMDoy6MEJQ5L@01iowCb1y&puZxZcrOx
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=webportal.pfx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - default
networks:
   default:
     external:
       name: maximohomepage
```

Following is the IP Tables of the server.

[image: IPTable]

I've tried pining the server from my desktop and it works as expected. However when I ping it with the port, it fails.
The certificate I'm using is valid.

Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Snippets" are only for HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Use the `{}` button (or four-space indents, or triple-backtick fenceposts before or after each code segment) to code-format other languages.

Comment: Beyond that -- things that are questions about system administration, rather than about writing code, are generally a better fit for [unix.se].

Comment: BTW -- when dumping your iptables rules, it helps to ask it to include the statistics about how many times each rule has been evaluated. That way you can tell when a rule isn't being invoked at all.